# searching for red colored words in docx file and extracting those words and text between those red colored words

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a word document with some words in red color. I want my program to read the word document using Python docx and search for the red colored words, and extracts extract those red colored words, but also the text between the red colored text.

The word document will look something like this:

Here is an example of a paragraph with no red colored words. This is another example of a paragraph with no red colored text.
This is another example of a paragraph with no red colored text.
red colored words here:HRD:100 Some text between red colored text. [RED:TEXT:1111]
This is another example of a paragraph with no red colored text.
This is another example of a paragraph with no red colored text.

so basically in this example, I want to extract these parts:
"red colored words here:RED:137"
and this part "Some text between red colored text." and this part "[RED:TEXT:1111]"
And save each part in 3 different lists.

Thank you so much for any help! I really appreciate it.

I know I can use this code to return a list of all contiguous parts of the document which are in red, but I also want to extract the text between the red words, and not just the red colored text.

```py
import docx
from docx.shared import RGBColor


def readtxt(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        for run in para.runs:
            if run.font.color.rgb == RGBColor(255, 000, 000):
                fullText.append(run.text)
    return fullText

fullText = readtxt('filepath.docx')
```

Answer (score 1):

> I also want to extract the text between the red words, and not just the red colored text.

As you mentioned using `python-docx` the red color text are parsed out, but not the words in between them. So to get the red color words with the words between them you need to do some more logic and it will be done.

So, I converted each paragraphs into a string of text and from that string using the colored words parsing the in-between words with the help of `split` method.

This is how you modify your code,

```
import docx
from docx.shared import RGBColor


def readtxt(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)

    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:

        # Concatenating list of runs to single a string
        sentence = "".join(r.text for r in para.runs)

        # Variables to hold the colored and un-colored text
        start, between = "", ""
        for run in para.runs:
            if run.font.color.rgb == RGBColor(255, 000, 000):

                if start == "":
                    start = run.text
                    between = sentence.split(start)[1]

                elif between != "":
                    end = run.text
                    between = start + between.split(end)[0] + end
                    fullText.append(between.strip())
                    start, between = "", ""

        # # Uncomment this only when the counting of the colored text is odd
        # if between != "":
        #     fullText.append(between.strip())

    return fullText


fullText = readtxt("filepath.docx")
print(fullText)
```

If the colored text is not a single string it may not parse the words as expected, so here's the better solution.

```
import docx
from docx.shared import RGBColor


def readtxt(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)

    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:

        # Getting the colored words from the doc
        if (getcoloredTxt(para.runs)):

            # Concatenating list of runs between the colored text to single a string
            sentence = "".join(r.text for r in para.runs)
            fullText.append(sentence)

    return fullText


def getcoloredTxt(runs):

    coloredWords, word = [], ""
    for run in runs:
        if run.font.color.rgb == RGBColor(255, 0, 0):
            word += str(run.text)

        elif word != "":
            coloredWords.append(word)
            word = ""
    if word != "":
        coloredWords.append(word)

    return coloredWords


fullText = readtxt(filename="filepath.docx")
print(fullText)
```

Comment: thank you, but it's not saving the un-colored text

Comment: But it's working for the word file I used, will you please attach your word document?